# Flutter Geolocator do not working in some region

Tags: flutter, geolocation, position, geolocator

I am testing my geolocation code in my flutter project. I am trying to recover the current position. When I test it from France, it works. But in Senegal it does not work. I need help. thank you.

This is my code:

```
void locationPosistion() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true);

    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition, zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

 
  }
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you are seeing when it is not working?

Comment: I don't have any error in my logs. It displays the address as null value.

Comment: It returns null for getCurrentPosition?

Comment: @DanHarms yes  the code below  returns null.

 ``Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true); ``